# MVC ActionLink GET not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following link

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Inspection")"><i class="fa fa-user-md"></i> Inspections</a>
```

In my route I have the following

```
routes.MapRoute("Inspections", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Inspection", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

In Visual Studio when I click the link it works, on my live server I get a white page with the following in bold
xxx - /inspection/ and also a link [To Parent Directory]

All of my other links in the Application is working fine and as expected
Now I have to go and overide the url in the address bar to go xxx/Inspection/Index

The Index method does also have [HttpGet]

Edit 1:
I tried the following, I also tried removing the route

```
routes.MapRoute("Inspection", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Inspection", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Edit 2:

Here is all the routes I have

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute("Login", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
        routes.MapRoute("Employees", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Employees", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
        //Added the following to try to fix issue
        routes.MapRoute("Inspection", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Inspection", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Edit 3:
in InspectionController.cs I have the following Index method

```
    // GET: Inspection
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new ActiveInspectionsViewModel());
    }
```

Edit 4:

Here is the blank page that opens (example)

xxx - /Inspection/

## xxx - /Inspection/

---

```
[To Parent Directory]
```

---

Edit 5:

I think were getting closer to the issue, I have disabled Directory Browsing now I am getting the 403 error, which is really weird because all my other Action links works (/Employees, /InspectionTemplates, /Clients, /Emails, /CompanyLevels) It is Just /Inspection that is causing the problem, my url is inspection.xxx.co.za can it be the park domain causing the problem?

Comment: Is this your default Route - Or do you have other routes?

Comment: I only had one route, let me update the question with all routes

Comment: What does the "Index" action method signature look like in the "Inspection" controller?

Comment: See updated question

Comment: But also remember, locally on my development pc it works it will actually display the Index.cshtml, but on the Live server it is the only ActionLink that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your route definitions.

```
routes.MapRoute("Login", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
   new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute("Employees", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          new { controller = "Employees", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute("Inspection", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          new { controller = "Inspection", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

All three definitions you registered has the same url pattern, `{controller}/{action}/{id}`.

So whenever you request a page, The request url will be matched against the registered route definitions and when it gets the first match, the request will be send to the controller-action specified in the definition.

So when you request `Inspection/Index,` it is matching to the first definition (*Login*) and the request will be send to Login/Index action method.

Since you do not have anything other than the custom pattern in all the three routes,you do not need those. Just remove those and keep the default one.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
                                                         id = UrlParameter.Optional }     
    );
}
```

Comment: That did not solve the problem, I have changed my routes to this but the problem is still there, when I click on the actionlink a blank page comes up with the following url in the address bar http://xxx/Inspection/ with the text described in my Question but as soon as I just add Index at the end the page loads correctly ie http://xxx/Inspection/Index

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with your routing. It could be an IIS setting for your app. What version of IIS you have ? Is directory browsing enabled ? If you are getting an issue in your web hosting, It could be a setting in your web hosting control panel to be changed. Try deploying your code to IIS webserver in your local machine and see whether you still get the issue. If not, talk to your web hosting

Comment: If it is IIS, (I am using IIS 8.0) what could it be. see my updated question after disabling Directory Browsing

Comment: Did it work on your local IIS ? I verified it with my local IIS and i am not getting this behavior. I have IIS 10

Comment: See my updated question, maybe that is causing the issue, I am still to try on local IIS,

Comment: Just curious to know. Rename your controller to Inspection2 and see it works. Is there a virtual directory called Inspection under the same IIS application ?

Comment: Apparantly IIS didn't like Inspection, Inspection2 did work, the GET did work, and I cannot see any virtual directories with that Name, im going to host it on a different Parkdomain but keep it Inspection (and not Inspection2) and see what happens

Comment: This is really Odd, I just checked another application of mine where I have a parkdomain login.xxx.co.za and when I go login.xxx.co.za/login it actually works didn't give me the same problem

Comment: Im going to accept your answer because it is your help and suggestions that lead me to finding the problem, the problem wasn't IIS, or Web.conf or my coding BUT a Folder called Inspection in the same root as the Folder Views and Inside Views I also had the folder called Inspection which is linked to the Controller InspectionController, this caused the problem.

Comment: Folder with same name ! that makes sense :)

Comment: Gosh, im going to enable FTP Publishing (Instead of winrar)